# How can you solve equations in PHP?

Tags: php, equation

I'm looking for a generalized equation solver in PHP.  This could either be in the form of in-built functionality, a library, or even integration with another language if it comes to it.  I am even comfortable with a joint solution that involves some combination of the above.  I need this for an educational website on which I am working.

Let me give a series of equations that I would ideally expect such a solver to deal with:

```
x+5=8 => x=3
x^2=5 => x=+/-sqrt(5) [exact solution in terms of sqrt, ln, or whatever] AND
         x=+/-2.236 [approximate solution to certain number of digits]
x+y=-3 [solve in terms of y] => y=-x-3
x^2=-5 => x=+/5i
x+y=3 and x-y=3 => x=3, y=0
```

I hope this is not a bridge too far.  If so, I'll build the functionality as each problem comes in-house, but if anyone knows of the proper library for such a set of problems, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), from their website:

> Sage is a free open-source mathematics software system licensed under the GPL. It combines the power of many existing open-source packages into a common Python-based interface.
>   Mission: Creating a viable free open source alternative to Magma, Maple, Mathematica and Matlab.

Sage has an AJAX-based [notebook interface](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/interactive_shell.html#the-notebook-interface), that is probably as good as an API that you can use from PHP.

Comment: +1 for the open-source option.  I think there is a reason that paid services are so  successful, though.  In things like this, you really need accuracy and flexibility.  I haven't tried Sage, but my guess is that they are not quite as stable as other solutions.

Answer (score 6):

First: **your math solutions are wrong**.

- x+5=8 evaluates to x=3
- x+y=-3, y evaluates to -x-3

etc.

To do the math: **[make an API call to Wolfram|Alpha](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/).**

Seeing as this is an educational venture, I would highly suggest that you do not create your own product and rely on third-party software.  I would personally go with [Wolfram Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), and probably their [pre-college solutions](http://www.wolfram.com/solutions/precollege/) or go with [Web Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/) for web interfaces.

**Note about Web Mathematica:** it uses JSP or Java Servlets for it's back-end technology. More about [specific technical details for Web Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/technology/) will be helpful.

Comment: It looks like he wants to use this commercially, so WolframAlpha could be a very expensive route to go.

Comment: It doesn't sound too commercial to me, but Vivek knows what he wants, at least.

Comment: Wow.  That was really stupid.  I corrected those math errors.  Thanks.  This is a non-profit.  I'll look into pricing on Alpha / Mathematica.  If it's not unreasonable, I think it very well could be a good way to go.  Thanks.

Comment: Wow, we're going to need a degree of magnitude more than 2000 API calls a month if we are at all successful.  (It's not unlikely that a given user would end up consuming 200-400 calls a month with eventually quite a few users.)  I've emailed them but if possible, if a solution could be found outside of a paid service, that would certainly be ideal.  Thank you, Levi.